# Ubuntu 14.04 does not see all of my RAM

Tags: 14.04, ram, bios

I Have a gateway GN 5048 with 4G Ram installed.  The BIOS see the ram but the Ubuntu OS (64 bit) does not.

```
sudo lshw | grep -A 8 bank
```

Shows:

```
*-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
             product: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
             vendor: 0x7F7F7F7F7F9B0000
             physical id: 0
             serial: 0xFFFFFFFF
             slot: J6H1
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
--
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
             product: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
             vendor: 0x7F7F7F7F7F9B0000
             physical id: 1
             serial: 0x00000000
             slot: J6H2
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
--
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
             product: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
             vendor: 0x7F7F7F7F7F9B0000
             physical id: 2
             serial: 0xFFFFFFFF
             slot: J6J1
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
--
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
             product: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
             vendor: 0x7F7F7F7F7F9B0000
             physical id: 3
             serial: 0x00000000
             slot: J6J2
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
```

free -m 
Gives:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3259       1925       1334         17         78        692
-/+ buffers/cache:       1154       2105
Swap:         2035          0       2035
```

System Settings shows Memory at `3.2 Gig`
System Monitor shows

```
3.2 Gig
```

Memory test fails due to:
/proc/meminfo reports: `3337820.0 kB` 
lshw reports: `4194304.0 kB`

FAIL: Meminfo reports `877039616` bytes less than lshw, a difference of 20.42%. Only a variance of 20% in reported memory is allowed.

What should I do to get all of my RAM in use by the OS?

3 days later I show free -m
free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3259       3054        205         17        344       1368
-/+ buffers/cache:       1341       1918
Swap:         2035          0       2035

This with only Mozilla running, one window.  Why 205 free??

@Byte Commander: lshw -c system |& grep width = width: 64 bits – 
How can I tell for sure if the graphics has reserved the memory? –

After a reboot...

free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3259        948       2311          6         52        356
-/+ buffers/cache:        539       2720
Swap:         2035          0       2035

Comment: Some of the RAM can be used by the iGPU.

Comment: Is your system peer chance using onboard graphics? Some of those boards reserve memory for the gpu. I had one where I could configure the amount of reserved memory in BIOS.

Comment: What is the output of `lshw -c system |& grep width`? 32 or 64 bit chipset? Note that this is not necessarily the same value as your CPU width.

Comment: Looks fine. The memory you don't see available as system RAM is probably reserved for the on-board graphics.

Comment: @dobey The problem I have with all of this is that when I had 2G installed, the system showed 2G. When I expanded to 3G, the system showed 3G. Now I have 4G, the system is reporting 3G. Does not compute...

Answer (score 0):

Why only 3.2 when you have 4 installed?  The motherboard on that machine can only see 4GB RAM total. You can see your system specs [here.](https://www.cnet.com/products/gateway-gm5048-media-center-pentium-d-3-ghz-2-gb-ram-500-gb-hdd/specs/)  Some of that RAM is reserved for system use (swap, running the OS itself, etc.) so you will never see 100% available.  Secondly, an add-in video card will also reserve whatever capacity it is from the system RAM.  So if you have a 512MB video card, and the system reserves 200-300MB of RAM, you'll only see 3.2 GB available.

Your biggest problem is that your machine has a 64-bit processor (specs [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/27518/Intel-Pentium-D-Processor-930-4M-Cache-3_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)) on a 32-bit board.  Switching to a 32-bit OS (Download Ubuntu 14.04 i386 [here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)) or upgrading to a machine with a 64-bit board will help you tremendously.

Comment: @Oliver K The problem I have with all of this is that when I had 2G installed, the system showed 2G.  When I expanded to 3G, the system showed 3G.  Now I have 4G,  the system is reporting 3G.  Does not compute...

Comment: Your motherboard only supports (sees) 4G total.  I had 4GB of Ram installed with a 1GB graphics card.  My available RAM was 2.7 GB.  That means the operating system took 0.3 GB (about 300 MB) and the graphics card took 1 GB.  [(4.0-0.3) -1] = 2.7.

Comment: So if your graphics card takes 0.5 GB and the system needs 0.3 GB, these come off the top.  If the max RAM your motherboard can address is 4GB, then [(4.0 - 0.5) - 0.3] = 3.2 GB as the maximum usable RAM.  Since 2GB is less than 3GB which is less than the maximum of 3.2, those will both show with no problem.  With 4GB you have exceeded the max capacity, so only the max capacity is available.  Try taking out the graphics card and seeing if you get more RAM available.

Comment: @Oliver K :  Video card removed and still showing 3.2G.  I tried Ubuntu 16.04 and still showing 3.2G.  Any other ideas??

Comment: Well it is strange.  Anyhow I just got a Dell Optoplex 380 with 4G Ram and Ubuntu 16.   It shows only 3.8 gig of Ram.  Wish something would show all of the ram use and where it is being used at the time.... I am finished with worrying about this.  Thanks all for your input.